# How to get ordered results from ArcGIS in case of using statistics with group by

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Now if I implement query via ArcGIS Server 10.7.1 using params like this including outStatistics, groupByFields:

```
params = { ....  
    'groupByFieldsForStatistics': 'DFIRM_ID',
    'outStatistics': '[{
        "statisticType": "count", 
        "onStatisticField": "OBJECTID", 
        "outStatisticFieldName": "Count"
    }]' }
```

And the results are like this:

```
records: 383

DFIRM_ID: 13245C
COUNT: 8286

DFIRM_ID: 06037C
COUNT: 10632

DFIRM_ID: 17031C
COUNT: 1879

DFIRM_ID: 13115C
COUNT: 2678

DFIRM_ID: 06001C
COUNT: 12788

DFIRM_ID: 04013C
COUNT: 32702

DFIRM_ID: 04025C
COUNT: 2428

DFIRM_ID: 48453C
COUNT: 60419
```

Now I am looking for how to get the results in ascending order or descending order.
Additional thing I need, getting the top 3 from the ordered results?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [orderByFields request parameter](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-map-service-layer-.htm#GUID-BA3B02CD-BD10-4F19-BFB5-72A04D49D005).  For retrieving only the top values, use resultRecordCount.